# One Java Class with Multiple .xml file

Tags: java, android, xml, mobile-application

I am currently working on an android project which is assessment-based. There will be one question displayed in each interface (separate .xml file). After that, according to each answer that the user has selected, the points will be accumulated at the end.

I would like to ask that whether one java class is enough or I need to create each java class for each .xml file?

Comment: One java file is enough

Answer (score 0):

One solution is that you dynamically change the layout using custom views. It works great as I am also doing an assessment based project and using it.

[Custom view example](https://medium.com/mindorks/android-custom-views-tutorial-part-1-115fa8d53be5) Here is simple but good example

Answer (score 0):

One java file is enough:

If your questions having the same kind of UI behavior then you can use ViewPager component for this.

The fragment is another option with which you can achieve the above case.

[Refer example](https://www.journaldev.com/10096/android-viewpager-example-tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

if you're using the same code for every interface It'll be better to use [ViewPager](https://medium.com/@cdmunoz/the-easiest-way-to-work-with-viewpager-and-without-fragments-c62ec3e8b9f3) because it'll handle view inflation for every question.